# Can I specify the type of a class that extends from another class?

Tags: typescript

In Typescript it is possible to say "the type of this variable is a specific class rather than an instance:"

`const x: typeof Animal = Animal`

It's also possible with generics to say that a type inherits another type:

`function myFunction<T extends Animal>(someAnimal: T) { /* ... */ }`

Can I do both and say that "the type of this variable is a specific class or a class that inherits from that class"?

If `y` had such a type, then I could do `y = Animal` or `y = Tiger`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "the type of this variable is a specific class or a class that inherits from that class

When you have `x: typeof Animal` *it already accepts Animal or anything that extends Animal*. This is because TypeScript is structurally typed.

Sample:

```
class Animal{
    animal: number;
};
class Tiger extends Animal{
    tiger: number;
};


let x: typeof Animal;
x = Animal;
x = Tiger;
```

And there are lots of reasons why this is a *good idea* : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html

## Update

Based on the comment

> Wait a sec. So this definitely works, but doing something like myFunction(x: typeof Animal) and then myFunction(Tiger) doesn't work - it gives an error about incompatible types. Why not??

It works as well.

```
class Animal{
    animal: number;
};
class Tiger extends Animal{
    tiger: number;
};

function iTakeAnimalClasses(x: typeof Animal){}
iTakeAnimalClasses(Animal);
iTakeAnimalClasses(Tiger);
```

Comment: Wait a sec. So this definitely works, but doing something like `myFunction(x: typeof Animal)` and then `myFunction(Tiger)` doesn't work - it gives an error about incompatible types. Why not??

Comment: Ahh... You know what, the reason it's not working for me is my two classes have constructors which have incompatible types. There's no way around that, is there?

Comment: Don't see a way around except explict allowance with union types